# Re-installing Ubuntu 12.04 using Windows Installer

Tags: 12.04, installation

I had been using Ubuntu till yesterday, and then removed it from a partitioned drive so that I could format the drive for some purpose. Then I created a new volume and tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 using the windows installer. It installed in the drive perfectly. When I gave the 'Reboot now' option, the system rebooted with windows 7 itself and I didn't get the option of booting Ubuntu 12.04 at all. Then I restarted the computer just to see windows 7 start again without the boot options. Please help me. I have a Lenovo Thinkpad with 500GB hard drive and windows 7 OS

Comment: did you use a liveUSB or wubi?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you damaged your bootloader after the reinstall. It needs to be repaired. First boot in your pc using a Ubuntu live cd / usb and use live boot. After Ubuntu boots up you need to install and run Boot-repair [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) . When that is done click Recommended Repair, reboot and done.

You can also use the terminal: Now bring up a terminal (ctrl alt t) and type:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/XXX
```

where XXX is the device of your Ubuntu install. (eg: `grub-install /dev/sdb`)
You can also use `/dev/disk/by-label/` if the partition you installed on has a label. You can determine the /dev node for such a device by running:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/
```

You can also run Fdisk. That will give you something like:

```
t         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0001bc54

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       18725   150403072   83  Linux
/dev/sda2           18725       19458     5884929    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           18725       19458     5884928   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 15.1 GB, 15103033344 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 14403 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 2048 * 512 = 1048576 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00068852

   Device Boot      Star       14403    14748656    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```